# Scope of Variable defined outside FOR loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

The code below is used to replace continuous duplicate characters in a string with just one occurrence

```
e.g. "AAAABBBB" -> "AB"
```

When I exit the for loop and print the value in temp, my expectation is to get the last letter of a string word. However, I get the first letter of the string (i.e., with the value I initialized the temp).

```
string processString(string word) {
  char temp = word[0];
  string result = "";
  int size = word.size();
  for(int i=0, temp=word[0]; i<size; i++) {
    if(word[i] == temp) {
      continue;
    } else {
      result += temp;
      temp = word[i];
    }
  }
  cout << "TEMP : " << temp << endl;
  return result + temp;
}
```

Results:

```
WORD: CJXEJACCAJEXJF
TEMP: C
Output of function: CJXEJACAJEXJC
```

But the above code works perfectly fine if I remove the re-initialization in the for loop:

```
string processString(string word) {
  char temp = word[0];
  string result = "";
  int size = word.size();
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    if(word[i] == temp) {
      continue;
    } else {
      result += temp;
      temp = word[i];
    }
  }
  cout << "TEMP : " << temp << endl;
  return result + temp;
}
```

Results:

```
WORD: CJXEJACCAJEXJF
TEMP: F
Output of function: CJXEJACAJEXJF
```

Any clue why this is happening? Why does re-initializing it in the FOR loop makes such a big difference?

Comment: The `for` loop will use the inner one, and never change the outer one.

Answer (score 2):

In the `for` loop, you are not re-initializing `temp`. You are creating a brand new `int` variable called `temp` that shadows the outer `temp`:

```
for(int i=0,temp=word[0];i<size;i++){
            ^^^^ brand new `temp'
```

Some compilers can be configured to warn about this:

```
$ g++ -Wshadow test.cpp
test.cpp: In function 'std::string processString(std::string)':
test.cpp:10:15: warning: declaration of 'temp' shadows a previous local [-Wshadow]
test.cpp:7:8: warning: shadowed declaration is here [-Wshadow]
```

Comment: Another good example of why compiling at a high warning level is a good idea!  Other compilers will also issue warning about conversion of int to char at the 'result+=temp' line.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct about shadowing, but just for reference, your function could be simply written as:

```
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::string unique(std::string const &source)
{
    std::string result;

    std::unique_copy(src.begin(), src.end(),
                     std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think that's the desired result (just collapsing runs of the same character), and the question was really about the printed value of `temp` ... perhaps the OP can clarify? (That output matches both OP's _good_ and _bad_ output AFAICS - it's only the _TEMP_ line that differs).

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0,temp=word[0];i<size;i++)
```

That declares two variables, `i` and `temp`, scoped *inside* the `for` statement. This `temp` hides the one declared outside the `for` statement.

Answer (score 1):

A new variable named `temp` is declared as an `int` in the `for` loop:

```
for(int i=0,temp=word[0];i<size;i++){
```

hiding the outer `char temp` variable, meaning the `char temp` variable is never used inside the `for`. The second version of the `for` loop does not declare a new `temp` variable by omitting the initialization.